# Remove data fields dynamically

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to to remove a field dynamically

```
$form->remove('email');
```

Since it works I get an error in the twig file saying

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, null given, called in
>   /Users/xom/Projects/tt/var/cache/twig/9/5/95df63c0279f2b5a5adc85a478d9689d895a956a73987966af771d1f551ece8b.php
>   on line 137 and defined") in "Back/Products/add.html.twig" at line 34.

This is the code at line 34 of twig file

```
 {{ form_row(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
```

I understand that the reason for getting this error is because the `form.email` is unset because of the call to `$form->remove('email'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the email field is available:

```
{% if form.email is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
{% endif %}
```